# Groupby with multiple conditions and count

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count, multiple-conditions

Hi would be great to get some help on this for Python Pandas.TIA
I have a dataframe which has 1M rows with below columns:

| PID | lurn_fls | locality | Comparision |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACT933 | 2 | Kambah | mbn:match both non-empty |
| ACT934 | 3F | Charwood | xne:mismatch neither empty |
| ACT935 | 3R | Glenden | mbe:match both empty |
| . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . |
| ACT155 | 4 | Glebe | xhe:mismatch h_empty |

I need to do a groupby "lurn_fls" and also count the different 'Comparision' column results per group, so that my result should look like below table. for eg:

| lurn_fls | mbn:match both non-empty | xhe:mismatch h_empty | xne:mismatch neither empty | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 600 | 12 | 15 | XXX |
| 2 | 700 | 10 | 14 | XXX |
| 3F | 800 | 8 | 10 | XXX |
| 3R | 900 | 6 | 12 | XXX |
| 4 | 500 | 4 | 10 | XXX |
| 5 | 400 | 2 | 14 | XXX |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas-crosstab):

```py
out = pd.crosstab(df["lurn_fls"], df["Comparision"])
out["Total"] = out.sum(axis=1)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
Comparision  mbe:match both empty  mbn:match both non-empty  xhe:mismatch h_empty  xne:mismatch neither empty  Total
lurn_fls                                                                                                            
2                               0                         1                     0                           0      1
3F                              0                         0                     0                           1      1
3R                              1                         0                     0                           0      1
4                               0                         0                     1                           0      1
```

Comment: Can the header be re-indexed in the above dataframe? Ex:
                                |Comparision|
| lurn_fls  |  mbe:match both empty  |  mbn:match both non-empty |  xhe:mismatch h_empty| xne:mismatch neither empty  | Total |
2                               0                         1                     0                           0      1
3F                              0                         0                     0                           1      1

Comment: @Ashu I'd recommend to open a new question here on StackOverflow. Put the sample dataframe there (with correct formatting) + expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'kind': ['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog'],
                   'height': [9.1, 6.0, 9.5, 34.0],
                   'weight': [7.9, 7.5, 9.9, 198.0]
    }) 
df.groupby('kind').agg(
max_height=('height', 'max'), min_weight=('weight', 'min'),)
```